# How could I rid off duplicates?

Tags: python, mongodb

Collection example:

```
key1 - site1
key1 - site1
key1 - site2
```

I need a result as:

```
key1 - site1
key1 - site2
```

As I know, it's possible with join in SQL

Could you advise, please, how I have to make with Python mongodb?

Comment: here each line is a record in mongodb  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unique indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) in mongodb.

You can create index on key `key1` so that the values of key1 across the collection will be unique.

```
db.collection.createIndex({key1:1}, {unique:true})
```

Comment: but it could be many key1 and it 's possible situation when many site1 (key1 - site1, key2 - site1). I meant unique index won't help.  I need just rid off duplicates.